# Visual Studio Code - Hide Git Changes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't seem to find the name of this piece of the VSCode interface in order to turn it off. You can see the image below:

[image: VSCode Interface]

I'd like to hide the colored git information from just beside the line numbers. Clicking on the different regions shows me the changes made to files - either deletions, new code, or amended existing code.

I've tried Googling "VS Code git changes bar" and "VS Code hide changes" but I can't seem to find the name of this feature/interface component in order to toggle it off.

Comment: That was it, @Alex - Gutter indicator. Would not have expected it to be called "gutter". Thank you!